# What is the advantage to build an executable JAR

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

Today at work I came across something interesting. Say i have an old java project that were compiled with an ant build file and we have converted this project into a maven project. So now to build this project, we only need to do a mvn install.

When i do call

```
mvn install
```

I get a myproject.jar under the target folder, along with all the dependencies under a lib folder inside the target folder.

To run the executable of this jar I need to do something like :

```
java -classpath $classpath com.myproject.Mainclass $myArgs
```

Where $classpath is the path to all of my external libs and where $myArgs is the arguments that is passed to the main function.

I came across this [website](http://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven) and I'm really considering to use the spring boot maven plugin to package my executable jar.

Wouldn't it be easier to execute it if all the dependencies are packaged in a single jar file ?

Why would I use the manual configuration vs the Spring Boot Maven Plugin for the executable jar ?

What are the pro and the cons of doing this ?

Comment: This idea is not new with Spring Boot. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

Comment: Jar size can get pretty large if you bring everything along, Some docker instances bring their own dependencies and you only have to bring your jar to fit in. Also, it is nightmarish to have a bunch of different SQL drivers.

Comment: @Compass size isn't a problem. When we do put things in production, we need to say to the integrator how to install and start the jar. We then schedule the jobs that start this executable. So wouldn't it be easier like I said to package everything in a single jar file ?

Comment: If I correctly understand the spring-boot maven plugin it picks things into the resulting jar which you don't like to have there..(I'm not sure..)

Comment: Best approach would be using maven-shade/maven-assembly-plugin and having a single jar executeable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the article you had linked covers with pros and cons how to do such single jar file packaging, I'll write out things that you need to consider if you want to use this approach.

---

## Pros:

### 1. Simplicity of deployment

Users don't have to maintain any dependencies. All they need to do to run the app is get the jar file and execute `java -jar file.jar`.

### 2. No easy way to update dependencies by user

If your app uses some external dependencies, you can be sure they are in version that you have chosen. Using "classic" approach user can easily update it by himself to the version that may require some migration steps in your app.

## Cons:

### 1. Size of final package

If your app has large dependencies, every update will require users to download the whole package,
even if dependencies haven't changed.

### 2. No easy way to update dependencies by user

To change a version of any dependency you will need to update the whole package, where using the old way you could update only the dependency jar.

---

Summarizing, if your app doesn't have any heavy (in sense of file size) dependencies, I'll personally use single jar file approach. Even if your dependencies changes frequently. It's a lot easier to change a single file, no matter if your app has to be updated or some of its dependency.

Comment: It actually sums up the same pros and cons that I came up with. Thank you !